# How to take a "num/den" type input in Java?

Tags: java

I want to take in input like this:

Enter a fraction(num/den):

I thought this would work,

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a fraction(num/den):");
numerator = input.nextInt();
input.next();
denominator = input.nextInt();
```

and divide symbol will be disregarded.

Comment: No. Just take it was a string and process it after.

Comment: Also, an easy way to split the string would be to use String.split(), splitting by the '/' and you will get an array of length 2. You can format each value in the array as an int

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve input data as below.

```
String input = scanner.nextLine();
```

You can can apply rules to format/use depending on your requirements afterwards

One way of doing it, use **/** as delimiter to split the text then convert into two **int** to divide. Then you'll end up having fraction.

```
String parts[] = input.split(your_chosen_delimiter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting it into two parts using [String#split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)).

```
String s = input.readLine();
String array[] = s.split("/");
double num = Double.parseDouble(array[0]);
double den = Double.parseDouble(array[1]);
```

Now, just **divide the two variables**.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is

```
String line = input.readLine();
int num = Integer.parseInt(line.substring( 0, line.indexOf("/") ));
int den = Integer.parseInt(line.substring( line.indexOf("/") + 1 ));
```

It will find the "/" and take the left part as the "num" and the rigth part as "den"